# Cannot assign $_POST['variable'] to an object property

Tags: php, class, object, post, oop

I'm fighting with code:

```
$worker = new Worker(); // :|
$worker->addWorker;
//testing                   
//testing
// $_SESSION['worker']->addWorker();
echo $_POST['name'];
echo $worker->name;
```

which should two last lines should show the same value. The assign method in class looks like that:

```
public function addWorker()
{
      $this->name = $_POST['name'];
      $this->surname = $_POST['surname'];
      $this->dob = $_POST['dob'];
      $this->skills = $_POST['skills'];
      $this->postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
      $this->street = $_POST['street'];
      $this->email = $_POST['email'];
      $this->tel = $_POST['tel'];
      $this->erefnumber = $_POST['erefnumber'];
}
```

I'v got declared class Worker properties. The problem is that I don't have any error, $worker->name just gives anything. echo $_POST['name'] works fine.

Comment: Why are you not calling addWorker as a function?

Comment: You may want to consider refining your Worker api. "addWorker" implies that you are adding a single worker to another worker...does this make sense? Maybe a better name would be something like "setFromArray". Then you can pass the $_POST array to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost fine, but you do:

```
$worker->addWorker;
```

while it should be:

```
$worker->addWorker();
```

Also, to improve readability of your code, I'd consider changing `addWorker()` to require array argument:

```
public function addWorker( array $postArray ) {
    $this->name = $postArray['name'];
    ....
```

and pass `$_POST` while invoking:

```
$worker->addWorker( $_POST );
```